# Sudo and git commands

Tags: git, macos, terminal, permissions

I have been trying to resolve permission problems with Terminal.

Git would accept only commands with sudo and entering password, which it makes pushing anything so long.

I have tried few advices I found online but none of them helped.

[image: Permission problem]

I will be very appreciative if you can help me out.

Thats whats comes up when i insert ls -l. ls -l outcome

When using sudo chown message is zsh: no such file or directory
[ls -l image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdQdN.jpg)

Comment: You already cloned the repo and yet tried to `git init` inside the master branch.

Comment: @t0mm13b it's okay to run `git init` in an existing git repo. For example after a common hook is deployed in the template, `/usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks` or `/mingw64/share/git-core/templates/hooks/`, `git init` can copy the hook into the current git repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change permissions to the `.git` folder.

```
sudo chown <user> /angelweb/.git -R
```

ps: don't do `git init` in an existent repository

Comment: If you have problems doing chown, check your OSX installation. Probably the fail are at OS level. As a workaround, you can re-clone the repository if you have it uploaded to a git server.

Comment: Hello. I think that what is the problem as I am not able to even create new directory without sudo. Can you please suggest what is the best way to repair OS system? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you post the result of `ls -lF` executed inside the directory?

Comment: Please, don't use screenshots, but proper formatting.
Anyway, try to make the folder `angelweb` belonging to you instead of root: `sudo chown <user> /angelweb -R`

Comment: Hello. Apologies for adding screen shoot as you might be able to tell i m a newbie using the format of this webpage.  when using this command terminal comes back with the message chown: -R: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, I misplelled the command. Try: `sudo chown -R <user> /angelweb`

Comment: Hello apologies to ask but when trying to push the files the following error comes along ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:angeldanailov: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Check your connectivity and your permission on the remove repository on Github. If you can't solve the problem, please, make another question. 
Question should contain just one topic at the time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your need to define whats wrong, use ls -l to see permissions. If the problem is there use chmod/chown to resolve it.